# Transfer learning inceptionv3

Tags: deep-learning, keras, inception

Why is training classifier on extracted features (from inceptionV3) is so much faster than simply stack classifier on topless inception model?

From my experience extracting features + training classifier takes roughly 3-10 times faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you extract the features, I'm assuming the features are stored somewhere. This means only the computation for each image is done only once.

When you stack layers on top of the inception model, even if the inception weights are frozen, the forward pass for the activations or features still need to be computed. This is extra computation time, since the inception weights are not changing.